# Questions for controller actions in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to make a chat function in my website. I am planning to make it like when user1 accesses to user2's profile, it shows a link to make a chat with user2. And when the user clicks the link, user_id in profile table passes to chat changeset of user 2(receiver's user_id).

To do this method, I want to use two actions of controller in a link. How can I do this??

Any suggestion for this method? is it going to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "two actions in controller in a link"?. The first paragraph looks OK and doable, but I can't understand the question.

Comment: Well.. I mean actions like new, show, edit or etc in controller. Can I make it work two actions in a link??

Comment: If you want to make two actions after one click just create third action that performs both of the two actions. Actions are just functions so you can combine them.

Comment: So i can just combine two actions in a action and then call it! thanks for ur help.